# Metal Effect on Trace Impedance and Ground

Tags: impedance, shielding, metal

I am working on a project that will have some impedance controlled traces running next to a large metal plate grounded at 1 point. I wanted to confirm that:

1) The metal plate will still impact the impedance of the traces even though it is grounded at only 1 point.

2) In fact, even if the metal was floating it would still impact the impedance of the traces...however it would be capacitivley coupled to system ground and so modeling it could not be done with a simple impedance calculator that assumes GND planes.

3) If the flex is placed on top of a large metal plate that is grounded at only 1 point, the metal plate will still provide some shielding.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The H and B fields can't read. So they will do the same no matter what voltage level or not you connect to any nearby metal.

Update: I didn't answer your Q3) as it's not really clear what type of shielding you are talking about. Maybe this is better for a separate question.